# Using controller methods when an object has not been instantiated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form for a new object, and I want to include a button which will call a method in the new object's controller before I save the object.

```
<%= button_to 'do thing', do_thing_object_path(), remote:true %>
```

...needs an object with an id in the brackets. How do I call a method without instantiating an object?

The aim is a 'new' form which will only create nested objects if the user selects to - the user hits the button, which calls a method in the parent object's controller, the method instantiates the nested object and fires a bit of javascript to display the partial for the nested form. All this before any object is actually created.

My routes include:

```
resources :objects do
    member do
      get 'show_thing'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have taken,

```
   member do
         get 'show_thing'
   end
```

It is a `member` path. The `member path` needs an **`id`**.

[Here is the reference of it](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Instead take `collection` path. The `collection path` doesnot require an `id`

```
resources :objects do
  collection do
    get 'do_thing'
  end
end
```

`do_thing_objects_url` will be the `url` formed

`<%= button_to 'do thing', do_thing_objects_path(), remote:true %>`

Answer (score 0):

Link will look like this:

```
<%= link_to 'do thing', do_thing_object_path(id: object.id), remote: true %>
```

Controller action will be

```
def some_action
  @object = SomeClass.new
end
```

create a file some_action.js.erb

```
$('#partial_container_id').removeClass('hidden');
```

Comment: Thanks for response - I did try that, I get a no matching routes error, missing :id. I'll update the question with the route.

Comment: do_thing_object_path(id: object.id)

Comment: My problem is that I don't yet have an object with an id - it could be that it's not possible to call a method with out an instantiated object (i.e. an object with an id, but I'm not sure.)